# Firebase - getValue in third child return null

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem, when I want get value from firebase, `getValue()` return null

`DataSnapshot appleSnapshot` and `DataSnapshot dataSnapshot` - in console I see Key and Value correctly in Firebase too

**Database Structure**

[image]

**Debugging**

[image]

`DataSnapshot setting` - return Key but don't return Value (null)

`String settingKey` - return correctly String Key

`String settingValue` - return null

Why i cant get Value from my deeper childs?

```
private void readData(final ValidateJoinInterface validateJoinInterface, final String name, final String password, final String user) {

    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot appleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                DataSnapshot setting = appleSnapshot.child(name).child("Settings").child("Password");
                String settingKey = (String) appleSnapshot.child(name).child("Settings").child("Password").getKey();
                String settingValue = (String) appleSnapshot.child(name).child("Settings").child("Password").getValue();

            }
            validateJoinInterface.validateJoin(correctName, correctPassword, correctUserId);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e("DTAG", "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What key return while you are getting key?

Comment: And where exactly you are getting null?

Comment: Return Key "Password" but dont return Value "Aaa", I have null when i try getValue from name{"Settings"{"Password":"null"}, but in database on site and appleSnapshot i have: name{"Settings"{"Password":"Aaa"}

Comment: there is no any child or value after Password node. then you will not getting any value so thats why its return null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `name` varaible holds a String value like in your example `Aa` and also assuming that `Aa` is a direct child of your Firebase root, to solve this, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference settingsRef = rootRef.child(name).child("Settings");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String name = dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue(String.class);
            String password = dataSnapshot.child("Password").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", name + " / " + password);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
settingsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output will be: `Aa / Aaa`.

Comment: Thanks Alex, i need change appleSnapshot to dataSnapshot and now I can get Value correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can getting any value like :

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(name).child("Settings").child("Password")
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Log.d(TAG,"KEY - "+messageSnapshot.getKey() + "VALUE - "+messageSnapshot.getValue());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Crashlytics.logException(databaseError.toException());
                        sendMessageListener.onSendMessageFailure(databaseError.getMessage());
                    }
                });
```